# Numbers padded to 7 characters in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel

I need the EEID "0" Padded to 7 characters in Excel. For example the first one will be 0000001, the 2nd will be 0000215, and so on... Not sure what the formula is?  Thanks
EEID 1, 215, 6261, 89898

Comment: `=text(A1,"0000000")`

Comment: Alternately use custom formatting on those cells with: `0000000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format the cells as *Custom* > *0000000*:

[image]